# Can one convert the strings in a dataframe column by reading an Excel file for the correct string conversion

Tags: python, excel, pandas, replace

This is my first post and I am new to python and pandas. I have several dataframes that have a column called Formation. This represents geological formations. I want to convert these to geological time periods. I have an Excel file that I created from the raw datasets that provides the conversion mapping.

| Formation | Time Period |
| --- | --- |
| Belly River | Upper Cretaceous |
| Bearpaw Formation | Upper Cretaceous |
| Bearpaw | Upper Cretaceous |
| Beaverhill Lake | Devonian |
| etc etc for 51 rows | etc |

I know I can use the example below that I found online.

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['1st old value','2nd old value',...],['1st new value','2nd new value',...])
```

However, I presently have 51 conversion rows in this Excel file and my project could easily grow as I find more data. I was thinking there must be an easier way. Can each dataframe read the Excel file  to find the matching string in its Formation column and replace it with the Time Period string? And if so how? Or must I first create a dataframe of my Excel conversion file and then have each dataframe read the conversion dataframe looking for a Formation match and replace with the appropriate Timeperiod string?  Either way if there is a simpler solution rather than the one huge line of code above I would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give the expected output? Do you want to replace the whole cell with something or a specific word?

Comment: The current string in Formation for each row  will be replaced by another string taken from the Time Period column of the conversion file. Which string that will be is dependent on what the formation string is in each dataframe. Unfortunately in geology many people use different formation names. I have Belly River Formation in one file and just Belly River in another. Both should be replaced with Upper Cretaceous. In one df alone I have over 500 rows each with its own formation string. Each cell will have it's existing Formation string changed to one of the Timeperiod strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using `pandas` `merge` method.

Let's say the Formation/Time Period data is in `FormationTimePeriods.xlsm` and you have a dataframe with a column named `Formation`.

You could then use something like this to create a TimePeriod column in the dataframe.

Where there isn't a match there will be NaN.

```py
import pandas as pd

periods = pd.read_excel('FormationTimePeriods.xlsm')

df  = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df = df.merge(periods, how='left')
```

So if the dataframe had a Formation column like this.

```
Formation
Belly River
Bearpaw Formation
Bearpaw
Beaverhill Lake
Beaver
Paw
Belly
```

You would end up with this.

```
           Formation      Time Period
        Belly River  Upper Cretaceous
  Bearpaw Formation  Upper Cretaceous
            Bearpaw  Upper Cretaceous
    Beaverhill Lake          Devonian
             Beaver               NaN
                Paw               NaN
              Belly               NaN
```

You can find more info on `merge` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: Thanks Norie! That was awesome. I do not need the formation column once complete but it helps to see both columns to do a df.head() to check that the conversion was done correctly. I can delete the formation column and rename Time Period to Formation once I have checked it. I need to read up on merge function because I did not think it would work that way. Where is the best documentation to understand how these joins work?

Comment: @MarkP I'll add a link to the `Pandas` documentation for `merge` to my answer. Might not be the best place to get a full grasp but it should be a start.